# Generate unique id in django from a model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to generate different/unique id per request in django from models field. I did this but I keep getting the same id.

```
class Paid(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User)
     eyw_transactionref=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4()) #want to generate new unique id from this field

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.8 or superior, [madzohan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30637668/11573842) is the right answer.

---

Do it like this:

```
#note the uuid without parenthesis
eyw_transactionref=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

The reason why is because with the parenthesis you **evaluate the function when the model is imported** and this will yield an uuid which will be used for every instance created.

Without parenthesis you passed just the function needed to be called to give the default value to the field and it will be called each time the model is imported.

You can also take this approach:

```
class Paid(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User)
     eyw_transactionref=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

     def __init__(self):
         super(Paid, self).__init__()
         self.eyw_transactionref = str(uuid.uuid4())

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

Comment: I did that..I'm now getting NULL in my db, it means it's not saving! Should I post my views?

Comment: If you have a default value then you won't need `null=True` in the field definition. I'll remove from the answer. Try without that.

Comment: Now getting this error IntegrityError at /pay/

(1048, "Column 'eyw_transactionref' cannot be null")    I removed blank=True also.

Comment: That's kind of weird. It should work, I'll put an override to the `__init__` method as an alternative.

Comment: Also try this with the default value, maybe it works: `default=lambda:str(uuid.uuid4())`.

Comment: Thanks so much now working! I made a mistake in my view! You rock :)

Comment: Lol! You're welcome :) Finally just for curiosity... what way worked? The first one?

Comment: Ah man, I dislike when the accepted answer makes use of something `uuid` that needs to be imported but it isn't in the answer. It just makes the answer that much better, ya know?

Comment: @teewuane I understand, but the answer addresses the OP questions, which was already using `uuid` without putting the import statement, that's why I didn't find it relevant to include :)

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution and it works, except that my generating function gets called 6 times... I would love to understand why, if you could please explain, that would be great. For info, I use django 1.7. Thanks.

Comment: @AdelaN Must likely because you are creating 6 models. This will call the function every time you instantiate an object from that model. That was the OP's original question

Comment: I ran into a serious technical problem. If I specify the uuid function for default, the resulting south migration has an actual hard-coded UUID in it. That absolutely wrong if I understand that correctly, every entity would get that same exact UUID which is hard-coded there?

Comment: I mean it would be the *same* for all the entities? That's really bad!

Answer (score 140):

Since version 1.8 Django has [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField)

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # other fields
```

Comment: This is the actual answer if you have Django1.8+ :)

Comment: @Sevenearths http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499836/does-djangos-new-uuidfields-default-attribute-take-care-of-the-uniqueness

Comment: I used your solution but the value keeps changing. Why is it?

Answer (score 30):

If you need or want to use a custom ID-generating function rather than Django's UUID field, you can use a while loop in the `save()` method. For sufficiently large unique IDs, this will almost never result in more than a single db call to verify uniqueness:

```
urlhash = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)

# Sample of an ID generator - could be any string/number generator
# For a 6-char field, this one yields 2.1 billion unique IDs
def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def save(self):
    if not self.urlhash:
        # Generate ID once, then check the db. If exists, keep trying.
        self.urlhash = id_generator()
        while MyModel.objects.filter(urlhash=self.urlhash).exists():
            self.urlhash = id_generator()
    super(MyModel, self).save()
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer from Google Code worked for me:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/south-users/dTyajWop-ZM/-AeuLaGKtyEJ

add:

`from uuid import UUID`

to your generated migration file.

Answer (score 1):

you can use uuid for this task.
UUIDField is a special field to store universally unique identifiers.
Universally unique identifiers are a good alternative to AutoField for primary_key. The database will not generate the UUID for you, so it is recommended to use default.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(
     primary_key = True,
     default = uuid.uuid4,
     editable = False)
```

for more detail visit this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uuidfield-django-models/#:%7E:text=UUIDField%20is%20a%20special%20field,of%20128%20bits%20as%20ids.)