# Does UUIDField's 'default' attribute takes care of the uniqueness?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just jumped into Django for a quick project and I figured there is a [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) in the models.

I am using this for an external id field that every model will have to expose the object. Will the `default` parameter handle the uniqueness or do I have to write it in the save? I mean I know there is practically no chance of values colliding, but just to know how it is done internally

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**How does UUID module guarantees unique values each time?**

[RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html)(UUID module specification) specifies three algorithms to generate UUIDs:

1. Using IEEE 802 MAC addresses as a source of uniqueness
2. Using pseudo-random numbers
3. Using well-known strings combined with cryptographic hashing

In all cases the seed value is combined with the **system clock** and a **clock sequence value** (to maintain uniqueness in case the clock was set backwards). As a result, the UUIDs generated according to the mechanisms above will be unique from all other UUIDs that have been or will be assigned.

Taken from RFC 4122 [Abstract](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html):

> A UUID is 128 bits long, and can guarantee uniqueness across space and
> time.

**Note:** Due to this uniqueness property of UUIDS, there is no check done by Django internally (as mentioned by @FlipperPA) to check if there already exists another object with the same `uuid`.

Answer (score 6):

Django doesn't enforce the uniqueness of UUIDs. That's because the main use case for UUIDs is to provide an identifier that can be expected to be unique *without* having to check with a centralized authority (like a database, which is what `unique=True` does).

(Note that UUIDs are not guaranteed to be unique, there is just [an astronomically small chance of a collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions).)

You certainly can use the database to enforce uniqueness on top of the UUIDs if you want (by setting `unique=True` on your field), but I would say that's an unusual, and hard to justify, configuration.

Comment: A lot of time has passed, but why " that's an unusual, and hard to justify, configuration". Is there any better alternative?

Comment: @funnydman: The alternative is the default behavior of not having the database check for uniqueness. The whole point of UUIDs is that they're effectively unique already.

Comment: thanks for the response. But actually I don't see any problems with having `unique=True` on the `UUIDField` field. Are there any real caveats?

Comment: @funnydman: The downside is the extra work the database has to do to enforce the uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not. Here is the relevant part of the code from Django:

```
def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
    if isinstance(value, six.string_types):
        value = uuid.UUID(value.replace('-', ''))
    if isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
        if connection.features.has_native_uuid_field:
            return value
        return value.hex
    return value
```

As you can see, when preparing the value for the database, it simple calls uuid with a replace on hyphens; there's no check for existing uniqueness. That said, the UUIDField inherits from class Field, which will obey Django's models unique definition.

Comment: So within a model objects, I can be sure that it is unique ? Or should I override save and add only unique uuid values

Answer (score 0):

I am fond of using UUIDs as primary keys and I am fond of not delivering 500 errors to end users for a simple operation such as create a login. So I have the following classmethod in my model. I siphon off some pre-assigned reserved guids for synthetic transactions on the production database and don't want those colliding either.  Cosmic lightning has struck before, a variant (instrumented to report collision) of the code below has actually fired the second attempt of guid assignment.  The code shown below still risks a concurrent write collision from a different app server, so my views go back to this method if write/create operations in the view fail.

I do ack that this code is slower by the time cost of the db lookup, but as guid is my pk it is not ridiculously expensive when the underlying db uses a b-tree index on the field.

```
@classmethod
def attempt_to_set_guid(cls,attemptedGuid=None):
    while(True):
        try:
            if attemptedGuid is None:
                attemptedGuid = uuid4() 
            elif (attemptedGuid in cls.reserved_guids):
                attemptedGuid = uuid4() 
                continue
            alreadyExists = Guid.objects.get(guid=attemptedGuid)
            break
        except Exception as e:
            break
    return attemptedGuid
```